# Given a bitonic array and element x in the array, find the index of x in 2log(n) time

Tags: algorithm, search

First, a bitonic array for this question is defined as one such that for some index `K` in an array of length `N` where `0 < K < N - 1` and 0 to K is a monotonically increasing sequence of integers, and K to N - 1 is a monotonically decreasing sequence of integers.

Example: `[1, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 11, 7, 2, -4, -9]`. It monotonically increases from 1 to 14, then decreases from 14 to -9.

The precursor to this question is to solve it in `3log(n)`, which is much easier. One altered binary search to find the index of the max, then two binary searchs for 0 to K and K + 1 to N - 1 respectively.

I presume the solution in `2log(n)` requires you solve the problem without finding the index of the max. I've thought about overlapping the binary searches, but beyond that, I'm not sure how to move forward.

Comment: I think a plausible route is to do two binary searches, assuming that the middle element is the max. Then, in both binary searches we include a constraint to watch out for some inconsistency, that is at some point one of the two halves are not monotonically increasing/decreasing. Once found, the binary search that plops on this adjusts itself accordingly. The question here would be what to watch out for.

Comment: However, if the middle was not the max, it is possible that the two binary searches will converge to one side, which means one would be redundant. In which case, we must force one of the binary searches the other way until it works itself out and doesn't move towards the other binary search. I think that would be how to go about it.

Comment: How does the search for the max work out to exactly log n with no constant factor anyway?

Comment: @JudgeMental http://flexaired.blogspot.com/2013/06/find-element-in-bitonic-array.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**The algorithms presented in other answers ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21697488/509868) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19373178/509868)) are unfortunately incorrect, they are not O(logN) !**

The recursive formula f(L) = f(L/2) + log(L/2) + c doesn't lead to f(L) = O(log(N)) but leads to f(L) = **O((log(N))^2)** !

Indeed, assume k = log(L), then log(2^(k-1)) + log(2^(k-2)) + ... + log(2^1) = log(2)*(k-1 + k-2 + ... + 1)  = O(k^2). Hence, log(L/2) + log(L/4) + ... + log(2) = O((log(L)^2)).

The right way to solve the problem in time ~ 2log(N) is to proceed as follows (assuming the array is first in ascending order and then in descending order):

1. Take the middle of the array
2. Compare the middle element with one of its neighbor to see if the max is on the right or on the left
3. Compare the middle element with the desired value
4. If the middle element is smaller than the desired value AND the max is on the left side, then do bitonic search on the left subarray (we are sure that the value is not in the right subarray)
5. If the middle element is smaller than the desired value AND the max is on the right side, then do bitonic search on the right subarray
6. If the middle element is bigger than the desired value, then do descending binary search on the right subarray and ascending binary search on the left subarray.

In the last case, it might be surprising to do a binary search on a subarray that may be bitonic but it actually works because we know that the elements that are not in the good order are all bigger than the desired value. For instance, doing an ascending binary search for the value 5 in the array [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 7] will work because 7 and 8 are bigger than the desired value 5.

Here is a fully working implementation (in C++) of the bitonic search in time **~2logN**:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int N = 10;

void descending_binary_search(int (&array) [N], int left, int right, int value)
{
  // cout << "descending_binary_search: " << left << " " << right << endl;

  // empty interval
  if (left == right) {
    return;
  }

  // look at the middle of the interval
  int mid = (right+left)/2;
  if (array[mid] == value) {
    cout << "value found" << endl;
    return;
  }

  // interval is not splittable
  if (left+1 == right) {
    return;
  }

  if (value < array[mid]) {
    descending_binary_search(array, mid+1, right, value);
  }
  else {
    descending_binary_search(array, left, mid, value);
  }
}

void ascending_binary_search(int (&array) [N], int left, int right, int value)
{
  // cout << "ascending_binary_search: " << left << " " << right << endl;

  // empty interval
  if (left == right) {
    return;
  }

  // look at the middle of the interval
  int mid = (right+left)/2;
  if (array[mid] == value) {
    cout << "value found" << endl;
    return;
  }

  // interval is not splittable
  if (left+1 == right) {
    return;
  }

  if (value > array[mid]) {
    ascending_binary_search(array, mid+1, right, value);
  }
  else {
    ascending_binary_search(array, left, mid, value);
  }
}

void bitonic_search(int (&array) [N], int left, int right, int value)
{
  // cout << "bitonic_search: " << left << " " << right << endl;

  // empty interval
  if (left == right) {
    return;
  }

  int mid = (right+left)/2;
  if (array[mid] == value) {
    cout << "value found" << endl;
    return;
  }

  // not splittable interval
  if (left+1 == right) {
    return;
  }

  if(array[mid] > array[mid-1]) {
    if (value > array[mid]) {
      return bitonic_search(array, mid+1, right, value);
    }
    else {
      ascending_binary_search(array, left, mid, value);
      descending_binary_search(array, mid+1, right, value);
    }
  }

  else {
    if (value > array[mid]) {
      bitonic_search(array, left, mid, value);
    }
    else {
      ascending_binary_search(array, left, mid, value);
      descending_binary_search(array, mid+1, right, value);
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int array[N] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 4, 1, 0};
  int value = 4;

  int left = 0;
  int right = N;

  // print "value found" is the desired value is in the bitonic array
  bitonic_search(array, left, right, value);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does "dichotomic_search" here mean "binary search"?

Comment: absolutely ! I've edited the post and replaced 'dichotomic_search' by 'binary_search' to be consistent with the explanation.

Comment: Can you explain your recurrence relation.

Comment: The assumption with the binary search does not work?
Say the array of integers `[2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1]` ?

Comment: @Sohaib: A (custom) binary search works as long as values are partitioned around searched value.We indeed cannot use std one (`std::binary_search` or `std::lower_bound`) as it will be UB.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that this breaks on arrays with repeated elements?

Comment: @Jehan Yes. There is an assumption that array contains distinct elements.

Comment: Insightful, thank you! The part I found confusing is we place ourselves in our situation where we have target > arr[mid], and then say binary search is okay in this setup. Well, the reason it is okay is that, taking the "ascending" (left) part of the mountain as an example, all points after the target are grater than it, so the array looks like [smaller than target, ..., smaller than target, (maybe target), bigger than target, ..., bigger than target], and in fact it is the sole assumption needed for binary search to work, even if the array is not perfectly sorted.

Comment: I agree on @Sohaib 's point here. This algorithm will not work for all input cases. 

For example, [2, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 1]. If you are searching for value 1 and when the mid is the index 5, value 8 will be bigger than 1 and the biggest will be on the left side.

Number 4 suggests: `If the middle element is smaller than the desired value AND the max is on the left side, then do bitonic search on the left subarray (we are sure that the value is not in the right subarray)`

However, in this case the searched value is on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm works recursively by combining bitonic and binary searches:

```
def bitonic_search (array, value, lo = 0, hi = array.length - 1)
  if array[lo] == value then return lo
  if array[hi] == value then return hi
  mid = (hi + lo) / 2
  if array[mid] == value then return mid
  if (mid > 0 & array[mid-1] < array[mid])
     | (mid < array.length-1 & array[mid+1] > array[mid]) then
    # max is to the right of mid
    bin = binary_search(array, value, low, mid-1)
    if bin != -1 then return bin
    return bitonic_search(array, value, mid+1, hi)
  else # max is to the left of mid
    bin = binary_search(array, value, mid+1, hi)
    if bin != -1 then return bin
    return bitonic_search(array, value, lo, mid-1)
```

So the recursive formula for the time is `f(l) = f(l/2) + log(l/2) + c` where `log(l/2)` comes from the binary search and `c` is the cost of the comparisons done in the function body.

Comment: I assume the method is began with lo being the first element and hi being the last element?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bitonic search, so I must ask: are `&` and `|` binary operations or shorthand for `&&` and `||`?

Comment: yes, these are the standard logical operations `and` and `or` (this is pseudocode)

Answer (score 1):

Answers those provided have time complexity of (N/2)*logN. Because the worst case may include too many sub-searches which are unnecessary. A modification is to compare the target value with the left and right element of sub series before searching. If target value is not between two ends of the monotonic series or less than both ends of the bitonic series, subsequent search is redundant. This modification leads to 2lgN complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public int FindLogarithmicGood(int value)
    {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = _bitonic.Length - 1;
        int mid;
        while (hi - lo > 1)
        {
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
            if (value < _bitonic[mid])
            {
                return DownSearch(lo, hi - lo + 1, mid, value);
            }
            else
            {
                if (_bitonic[mid] < _bitonic[mid + 1])
                    lo = mid;
                else
                    hi = mid;
            }
        }

        return _bitonic[hi] == value 
            ? hi
            : _bitonic[lo] == value 
                ? lo
                : -1;
    }
```

where DownSearch is

```
    public int DownSearch(int index, int count, int mid, int value)
    {
        int result = BinarySearch(index, mid - index, value);
        if (result < 0)
            result = BinarySearch(mid, index + count - mid, value, false);
        return result;
    }
```

and BinarySearch is

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Exactly log(n) on average and worst cases.
    /// Note: System.Array.BinarySerch uses 2*log(n) in the worst case.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>array index</returns>
    public int BinarySearch(int index, int count, int value, bool asc = true)
    {
        if (index < 0 || count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        if (_bitonic.Length < index + count)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        if (count == 0)
            return -1;

        // "lo minus one" trick
        int lo = index - 1;
        int hi = index + count - 1;
        int mid;
        while (hi - lo > 1)
        {
            mid = lo + ((hi - lo) / 2);
            if ((asc && _bitonic[mid] < value) || (!asc && _bitonic[mid] > value))
                lo = mid;
            else
                hi = mid;
        }

        return _bitonic[hi] == value ? hi : -1;
    }
```

[github](https://github.com/dlarionov/algorithms/tree/master/Part%20I/IQ/02%20-%20Analysis%20of%20Algorithms/Search%20in%20a%20bitonic%20array)

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 main cases depending on where the max element of array is, and whether middle element is greater than desired value

Calculate middle element.
Compare middle element desired value, if it matches search ends. Otherwise proceed to next step.

1. Compare middle element with neighbors to see if max element is on left or right. If both of the neighbors are less than middle element, then element is not present in the array, hence exit.(Array mentioned in the question will hit this case first as 14, the max element, is in middle)
2. If middle element is less than desired value and max element is on right, do    bitonic search in right subarray
3. If middle element is less than desired value and max element is on left, do bitonic search in left subarray
4. If middle element is greater than desired value and max element is on left, do descending binary search in right subarray
5. If middle element is greater than desired value and max element is on right, do ascending binary search in left subarray

In the worst case we will be doing two comparisons each time array is divided in half, hence complexity will be 2*logN

Answer (score 0):

Finding the change of sign among the first order differences, by standard dichotomic search, will take `2Lg(n)` array accesses.

You can do slightly better by using the search strategy for the maximum of a unimodal function known as Fibonacci search. After n steps each involving a single lookup, you reduce the interval size by a factor `Fn`, corresponding to about `Log n/Log φ ~ 1.44Lg(n)` accesses to find the maximum.

This marginal gain makes a little more sense when array accesses are instead costly funciton evaluations.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to searching Algorithms in O(log N) time, You gotta think of binary search only.
The concept here is to first find the peak point,
for ex: Array = [1 3 5 6 7 **12** 6 4 2 ] -> Here, 12 is the peak. Once detected and gotta mark as mid, Now simply do a binary search in Array[0:mid] and Array[mid:len(Array)].

Note: The second array from mid -> len is a descending array and need to make a small variation in binary search.

For finding the Bitonic Point :-) [ Written in Python ]

```
start, end = 0, n-1
while start <= end:
    mid = start + end-start//2
    if (mid == 0 or arr[mid-1] < arr[mid]) and (mid==n-1 or arr[mid+1] < arr[mid]):
    return mid
    if mid > 0 and arr[mid-1] > arr[mid]:
        end = mid-1
    else:
        start = mid+1
```

Once found the index, Do the respective Binary Search. Woola...All done :-)

Answer (score -2):

For a binary split, there are three cases:

1. max item is at right, then binary search left, and bitoinc search right.
2. max item is at left, then binary search right, and bitoinc search left.
3. max item is at the split point exactly, then binary both left and right.

caution: the binary search used in left and right are different because of increasing/decreasing order.

```
public static int bitonicSearch(int[] a, int lo, int hi, int key) {
    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
    int now = a[mid];
    if (now == key)
        return mid;
    // deal with edge cases
    int left = (mid == 0)? a[mid] : a[mid - 1];
    int right = (mid == a.length-1)? a[mid] : a[mid + 1];
    int leftResult, rightResult;
    if (left < now && now < right) { // max item is at right
        leftResult = binarySearchIncreasing(a, lo, mid - 1, key);
        if (leftResult != -1)
            return leftResult;
        return bitonicSearch(a, mid + 1, hi, key);
    }
    else if (left > now && now > right) { // max item is at left
        rightResult = binarySearchDecreasing(a, mid + 1, hi, key);
        if (rightResult != -1)
            return rightResult;
        return bitonicSearch(a, lo, mid - 1, key);
    }
    else { // max item stands at the split point exactly
        leftResult = binarySearchIncreasing(a, lo, mid - 1, key);
        if (leftResult != -1)
            return leftResult;
        return binarySearchDecreasing(a, mid + 1, hi, key);
    }
}
```

Comment: `max item stands at the split point exactly` - misleading comment