# Searching the element in array with complexity better than O(n)

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have any array where the elements are first in increasing order and then in a decreasing order

Like A[10]={1,4,6,8,3,2} , with no duplicates in an array.

if the input is 7, Output should be, Element do not exist.

Time complexity should b better thn O(n)

I am getting the result by the linear search, comparng each elemnts with the element to b found. But as I want solution better then O(n)

I tried by finding a pivot where the array element flips, and then searching from (0 to pivotelement) and then again searchiing in (last elemnt to pivot elemnt).

Please suggest.
For O(n)

```
 #include<iostream>
 int main()
 {
     int A[10]={1,4,6,8,3,2};
     int i,num
     cout<<"Enter the element to be searched";
     cin>>num
     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
         If(A[i]==num)
        {
          cout<<"Element exist";
         break;
      }
         else
         cout<<"Element do not exist";
     }
 }
```

Comment: So you tried something. Where is your code?

Comment: Search for Dichotomy algorithm. It does the job in O(logN).

Comment: You can also build a binary tree and search from within. It takes O(logN). Dichotomy is the same idea of binary tree without just building it.

Comment: I guess you want a code to do this. Share what have you done in O(n).  Add the code to the body of the question.

Comment: Do you know the index of the maximum element? If so, make a binary search on the first part left of it, and, if not found, on the remaining part.

Comment: This is discussed in detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372930/given-a-bitonic-array-and-element-x-in-the-array-find-the-index-of-x-in-2logn

Comment: BTW, your linear algorithm is broken, you actually only check first element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a bitonic array and element x in the array, find the index of x in 2log(n) time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372930/given-a-bitonic-array-and-element-x-in-the-array-find-the-index-of-x-in-2logn)

Answer (score 5):

**Algorithm:**

1. Find max in log(n) by doing a binary search and save its index.
2. Do a binary search on the two sides of max.
3. If not found and the element doesn't equal the max, then it doesn't exist.

How to do step 1 ?

- pick the middle of the array
- check it against the item on the left  (your neighbour). If greater, then max is on the right side. Otherwise, we started in the decreasing sequence and max is on the left side. The way to choose wether to search on the right/left depends if the item on the left is greater/smaller.

**EDIT**
Just in case it was not clear: if you pick n/2-th element and turns out max is on the left, then you pick n/4-th element, if the max is on its right side, you only continue the search in the range `n/4...n/2` elements.

Comment: You should explicit how to find the maximum by binary search.

Comment: Binary search is a fairly simple algorithm, as long as the criterion for the search (i.e. what is being sought) is specified.

Comment: @YvesDaoust check it now.

Comment: @TonyTannous: the important thing to say is that you must compare neighboring elements. (Actually you are performing a standard search for 0 in the first order difference.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust checking the element on the left is your neighbour.

Comment: @TonyTannous: I know, why do you tell me ?